# Add different new values to several existing totals

Tags: microsoft-excel

Below is the answer to a previous question.

You can achieve what you wish to do using VBA Programming. In your worksheet default named say `Sheet1` you have say cell `A1` that shall be overwritten every month and cell `B1` is where you wish to see commulative total.

Right click on `Sheet1` and click View Code. Alternatively press `ALT + F11` and double click on the Sheet1 on left pane under VBA Project.

A blank VBA code window shall open. Enter the following code therein.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

Else
   If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value) Then
        Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value + Range("A1").Value
   Else

   End If
End If
End Sub
```

Save and exit.

Save the workbook as filename.xlsm. i.e. Macro enabled workbook.

Now as you overwritten the value in cell `A1` it shall get added to `B1`. Ensure that you update `A1` only when intended else it shall just keep on adding it to `B1`.

There's no such validation implemented in this code such that `A1` should only get updated once a month! Just a basic check that `A1` should be numeric to prevent run time error.

I found that this  works great for one of my  projects.

The question is, how I can change this, to work with several items all being independent.

Comment: FYI, `Range(Target.Address)` is exactly the same thing as `Target`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly how you want several items, this could be done in different ways.
If you just want to extend the functionality downward, you only need to introduce a bit of flexibility in the code, like this:

```vbs
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("A1:A10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing And IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value + Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Where the `KeyCells` will govern how long the list is and the `1` in `Target.Offset(0, 1)` represents output – column "B" in this case.